# How can we integrate Python code in AIML?

Tags: python, pyautogui, aiml

I am new to Python. I am currently doing a project which is kind of automation. The overall theme is get input via Chatbot and automate through PythonAutoGUI. I have downloaded one Chatbot. It consisted of AIML. Can we intgrate Python code inside AIML? Is it possible? If it is, How? I can't find relevant tutorials or information regarding this. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Program-y it’s 100% python and full aiml 2 compliant and has custom extensions to call python objects